# Find the critical points of each of the functions below and classify them as a local maximum, minimum, or neither

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

$f ( x , y ) = \ln ( 2 + \sin ( x y ) )$. Consider only the critical point $(0,0)$.

I have solved for the first and second partial derivatives and I see that they are both equal to $0$ at $(0,0)$. One of the exercises in my textbook mentions the Hessian matrix and I think I should be using that, but I am not sure how it works.

$f ( x , y ) = \left( x ^ { 2 } + 3 y ^ { 2 } \right) e ^ { 1 - x ^ { 2 } - y ^ { 2 } }$

For this problem, I took the first and second partial derivatives and I observed that the critical points are at $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$, and $(0,0)$. Do I have to use the Hessian here as well? How would that work?

Comment: If $xy > 0$ then $f(x,y) > f(0,0)$ if $xy < 0$ then $f(x,y) < f(0,0)$  This suggests to me that if you have a critical point, it must be a saddle point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one we have

$$f ( x , y ) -f(0,0)= \ln ( 2 + \sin ( x y ) )-\ln 2=\frac{xy}2+o(x^2+y^2)$$

and then it is a saddle point.

For the second one we have

$$f ( x , y ) = \left( x ^ { 2 } + 3 y ^ { 2 } \right) e ^ { 1 - x ^ { 2 } - y ^ { 2 } }\ge  \left( x ^ { 2 } +  y ^ { 2 } \right) e ^ { 1 - x ^ { 2 } - y ^ { 2 } }=r^2e^{1-r^2}=er^2-r^2+o(r^2)$$

that is positive as $r\to 0$ and therefore it is a minimum.

Comment: Can you please explain why you did $f(x,y) - f(0,0)$? Does this have to do with the Hessian?

Also, where did the $r$ come from in the second part?

Comment: @MohammedShahid For the first function $f(0,0)=\ln 2$ and we are interested to the change $f(x,y)-f(0,0)$. For the second one $f(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean by, "we are interested in the change". 

Also, why does $\frac{xy}{2}+o(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ imply that there is a saddle point?

Also, what does the $o(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ mean?

Comment: Are you aware about Taylor's expansion or at least first order expansion?

Comment: I know about Taylor series that give polynomial approximation of a function. Is this similar?

Comment: @MohammedShahid Yes of course, for the first one just let $xy=t \to 0$ and for the second one just refer to polar coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain the first one again? I am still not understanding why this is a saddle point. Where do you get $xy=t \to 0$ from?

Comment: @MohammedShahid Because near (0,0) the function behaves llike $xy$ indeed the $o(x^2+y^2)$ term is smaller than $xy$ for $(x,y)\to (0,0)$

Comment: @MohammedShahid Sorry there was a typo in the littel-o term for the first one now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes a graph is worth a thousand words:

[image]

As @gimusi points out, this is clearly a saddle point.

Here's your second function:

[image]

Clearly a minimum because for any $r>0$, a point a distance $r$ from $(0,0)$ is above the point at the origin.  The second derivative with respect to $x$ evaluated at $(0,0)$ is $e$ ($>0$) and hence the origin is a minimum.

Comment: That's confirm also the second one is  a minimum! Thanks